# Re-using top level models with gson

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I am using GSON to parse a JSON response.

If I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
"X" : {
     "Y" : [
         {
             "a" : "x",
             "b" : "y"  
         },
       ....
     ]
},
"A" : {
     "Y" : [
         {
             "c" : "1",
             "d" : "2"
         },
        ....
     ]  
}
```

I want to be able to re-use "Y" , but have the contents of Y parsed into different models at runtime.

If I define a top level model TopJson.java and define the fields as

```
private ModelX X;
private ModelA A;
```

and I define ModelX.java as:

```
private ModelY Y;
```

and ModelA.java as :

```
private ModelY Y;
```

and ModelY.java as :

```
private List<Something> results;
```

How can I use generics to ensure that ModelY can contain different types of models? How can I handle the case when I don't know what the structure of the JSON looks like?

Comment: have you tried the `Object` type?

Comment: I don't think Gson will know how to interpret it if I specify Object.